# Repeatly replace a delimiter at a given count (4), with another character

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Given this line:

```
12,34,56,47,56,34,56,78,90,12,12,34,45
```

If the count of the commas(,) is greater than four, replace 4th comma(,) with `||`.

If the count is lesser or equal to 4 no need replace the comma(,).

I am able to find the count by the following `awk`:

```
awk -F\, '{print NF-1}' text.txt
```

then I used an if condition to check if the result is greater than 4. But unable to replace 4th comma with ||

Find the count of the delimiter in a line and replace the particular position with another character.

## Update:

I want to replace comma with `||` symbol after **every** 4th occurrence of the comma. Sorry for the confusion.

**Expected output:**

```
12,34,56,47||56,34,56,78||90,12,12,34||45
```

Comment: What should happen if the count is exactly 4? You only specified >4 and <4.

Comment: @ex-bart, i have updated my question

Comment: @Marjer do not update your question. If it is different, ask a different one. So far, they are free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
s='12,34,56,47,56,34,56,78,90,12,12,34,45'
awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i%4?FS:"||"); print $i}' <<< "$s"
12,34,56,47||56,34,56,78||90,12,12,34||45
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, i have updated my question. Exceptecd output: 12,34,56,47||56,34,56,78||90,12,12,34||45

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk for [`gensub()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

```
$ echo '12,34,56,47,56,34' | awk -F, 'NF>5{$0=gensub(/,/,"||",4)}1'
12,34,56,47||56,34

$ echo '12,34,56,47,56' | awk -F, 'NF>5{$0=gensub(/,/,"||",4)}1'
12,34,56,47,56
```

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton, i have updated my question Exceptecd output: 12,34,56,47||56,34,56,78||90,12,12,34||45

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo 12,34,56,47,56,34,56,78,90,12,12,34,45 | sed 's/,/||/4'
12,34,56,47||56,34,56,78,90,12,12,34,45
$ echo 12,34,56,47 | sed 's/,/||/4'
12,34,56,47
```

Should work with any POSIX sed

**Update:**

For the updated question you can use

```
$ echo 12,34,56,47,56,34,56,78,90,12,12,34,45 | sed -e 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}[^,]*\),/\1||/g'
12,34,56,47||56,34,56,78||90,12,12,34||45
```

Unfortunately, POSIX sed's `s` command can take either a number or `g` as a flag, but not both.  GNU sed allows the combination, but it does not do what we want in this case.  So you have to spell it out in the regular expression.

Comment: I had that too but it fails as it'll replace the 4th `,` with `||` when the count is **equal to** 4 whereas the OP only wants it replaced if the count is **greater than** 4.

Comment: @EdMorton Good point.  I read the question again, and noticed that  he did not specify what should happen if the count is exactly 4, so I stand by this answer until he clarifies his question.

Answer (score 0):

> if the count is greater than four i want to replace 4th comma(,) with
>   ||

give this line a try (gnu sed):

```
sed -r '/([^,]*,){4}.*,/s/,/||/4' file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo ",,,,,"|sed -r '/([^,]*,){4}.*,/s/,/||/4'
,,,||,

kent$  echo ",,,,"|sed -r '/([^,]*,){4}.*,/s/,/||/4'    
,,,,

kent$  echo ",,,"|sed -r '/([^,]*,){4}.*,/s/,/||/4'     
,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

with awk

```
 awk -F, 'NF-1>4{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if(i==4)k=k$i"||";else k=k$i","} print k$NF}' filename
```